# Agreement in the case of using maps api by android webview

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, webview

I've created Android application using Maps API V3 on WebView and
local HTML files(contained in an APK as resource files).
And I'm going to do free distribution of this application by GooglePlay.

I read the use agreement of Maps API.
But, I can't understand whether this usage is right on agreement, or not.
I think Maps API agreement assumes use by a website.

Please let me know whether my application is satisfactory to API agreement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine as long as you're not doing anything else prohibited by the agreement. In the terms, https://developers.google.com/maps/terms, take a look at sections 9.1, 9.1.1, 9.1.2(b)